# Regex to handle OR conditions in hdfs directory listing

Tags: regex

I have 100+ directories in my hdfs home directory but I am interested in listing very few only. Could you please help me with a regex for that.

Under /my/home I have 100 directories (one,two,three...hundred), in that I want to list only "eight, nine, ten, twenty and few others", tried multiple patterns but nothing is working (basically i want to include a OR condition so that whichever is available it will list).

/my/home/(eight|nine|ten|twenty|thirty)  -- this is not working for me.. any suggestions..?

Comment: Where are you using the regex? Linux cmd line? A tool?

Comment: I am using in the hadoop command

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
/my/home/{eight,nine,ten,twenty,thirty}
```